# Jquery event.repeat() syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, repeat, 2d-games, pong

I am trying to use jQuery to program pong. I want the ball to be moving indefinitely but I don't know how to get my event to occur more than once. I am using `keydown` and `keyup` for moving the barrier at the bottom and want a way that moves the ball and allows me to continue moving the two barriers.

I have a function that determines which way to move the ball, and i want to repeat that function intermittently.
I tried `moveball().repeat('Infinity');` and `$(".ball").moveball().repeat('Infinity');`
but I don't think this is the right syntax.

The relevant information from `moveball()` is below:

```
    function moveball(){
        $(".ball").animate({top: '+='+ 40 + 'px'},10);   
    }
```

Comment: .repeat() isn't a function... plus you'll need to define how often it repeats. I doubt you want it going full tilt, that would prevent the move from even rendering on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var loop = setInterval(moveball, 50);`

this will repeat moveball every 50 milliseconds. call `clearInterval(loop)` to stop it.

Comment: Thanks kevin. setInterval actually returns the interval ID. `clearInterval(loop)` is what I was looking for.